# Исправьте код python

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код к задаче не работает при первом тесте(выдает результат 2), при втором все работает исправно.

```
word = input()
n = int(input())
dword = {i: word.count(i) for i in set(word)}
count = 0
for _ in range(n) :
    words = input()
    tmp = {i: words.count(i) for i in set(words)}
    flag = 1
    for i in list(tmp.keys()) :
        if i not in dword or tmp[i] > dword[i] :
            flag = 0
            break
    count += flag
print(count)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в задаче за правильное слово надо прибавлять кол-во букв в слове, а вы прибавляете просто 1

```
count += flag
```

вот чуть по другому код переписал:

```
text = input()
letters_total = {i: text.count(i) for i in set(text)}

count = 0
for _ in range(int(input())) :
    word = input()
    letters_local = {i: word.count(i) for i in set(word)}

    is_corrent = True
    for letter in letters_local:
        if letter not in letters_total or letters_local[letter] > letters_total[letter]:
            is_corrent = False
            break

    count += len(word) if is_corrent else 0

print(count)
```

немного более короткий, но и более извратный код:

```
text = input()
letters_total = {i: text.count(i) for i in set(text)}

count = 0
for _ in range(int(input())) :
    word = input()
    letters_local = {i: word.count(i) for i in set(word)}

    count += len(word) if [0 for letter in letters_local if letter not in letters_total or letters_local[letter] > letters_total[letter]] == [] else 0

print(count)
```